# How split up useEffect into several custom hooks or files?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm a bit baffled by the logic behind react useEffect and custom hooks.

I have a useEffect call that is only called once on load. It has tons of variables that are disposed after the first use. I tried to split it up into several custom hooks.

Current huge code:

```js
function App() {
  useEffect(()=>{
    // tons of code to load and parse a CSV
    ...
    // tons of code to create a drawing from the csv
    ...
    // tons of code to appy an algorithm to the csv data
    ...
    // finished. show a result. never use the data / drawing again.
  },[])
}
```

My expectation for using custom hooks:

```js
function App() {
  useEffect(()=>{
    let data = useCSVLoader()
    let drawing = useDrawing(data)
    let algorithm = createAlgorithm(data)
  },[])
}
```

But according to the documentation I HAVE to put the custom hooks in the main function body? But since they are dependent on each other, how do I know they are called in the right order? Does each custom hook need an internal `useEffect`?

Would the following assumption be correct?

```js
function App {
    let data = useCSVLoader()
    let drawing = useDrawing(data)
    let algorithm = createAlgorithm(data)
    useEffect(()=>{
       // nothing here anymore?
    },[])
}
```

Comment: why not use one `useEffect` and split code in normal functions, like csvLoader, drawing, createAlgorithm, etc.? Why split it into many hooks?

Comment: There is most likely a huge misunderstanding happening here. Not all code that is called from within a render function needs to reside in a hook.

Comment: But after a rerender, won't all code outside of useEffect get called again?

Comment: can we move this to a [chat]?

Comment: sorry I can't figure out how to open a chat for this question

Comment: I created a room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253129/useeffect-room

Answer (score 0):

Your can return functions from your custom hooks `useDrawing` and `useCreateAlgorithm` that will be called in the main `useEffect` when `data` is available, something like this:

```
const useDrawing = () => useCallback((data) => { 
  // your logic here
}, []);

const useCreateAlgorithm = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  return useCallback((data) => {
    // your logic here
  }, []);
}

function App {
    let data = useCSVLoader()
    let drawingFn = useDrawing();
    let algorithmFn = useCreateAlgorithm();

    useEffect(()=>{
      if(data) {
        const drawing = drawingFn(data);
        const algorithm = algorithmFn(data)
      }
    },[data, drawingFn, algorithmFn]);

    ...
}
```

Comment: That's very insightful! But I don't want data to be a state since it's really huge, it's an array with more than 500.000 entries. I just load it once and discard it.

Comment: You can return a simple array from the `useCSVLoader()` hook, you could also use `useMemo()` to memoize it so that it remains stable over renders

Comment: But that means it stays in memory, I want to discard it. But perhaps I can just empty the state after the algorithm has finished by using `setData(null)`!

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the last part of your comment carefully, yes you can set state to null and since you have a condition in the `useEffect` the functions will not be re-executed

Answer (score -1):

if the data is async you could something like this

```
function App {
    const [csvData,setCsvData] = useState() 
    let data = useCSVLoader()
    let drawing = useDrawing(csvData)
    let algorithm = createAlgorithm(csvData)

    useEffect(()=>{
       if(data) {
        setCsvData(data)
       }
    },[data])
}
```

so when the data is available it triggers the useEffect and sets the data when the data is available

in the custom hook where you get the prop data check for the presence of data like this so we can prevent unwanted renders

```
useEffect(()=>{
   if(!props.data) { return }
   // write your logic
},[props.data])
```

Comment: But, when the component re-renders (for some other reason, for example a user clicks a button), won't all those functions be called again?

Comment: And also, I don't want data to be a state, since it's huge.

Comment: then you could just have the useEffect in the custom hook which receives data and have the data prop in  dependency array  and return if the data is empty